# mixing modules with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 with modules without it?

Tags: linux, large-files

I'm guessing it's not kosher to have a library routine open a file in a module compiled with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 and then pass the handle back to a caller in a module compiled without that?

The code is being ported from AIX to Linux, and in AIX the equivalent is _LARGE_FILES=1.

Anyway, in AIX, as long as the file isn't *really* bigger than 2GB, this works fine, so most modules are not compiled for large file support.  And I'm wary of setting _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 in a common config.h file, because then the compiler will start complaining about stuff like  int file_size = ftell(file, 0, SEEK_END);.  But as it is, ftell(..., SEEK_END) is returning 0 on linux, so that's not good...

Comment: You might want switch to 64-bit mode.

Comment: 64-bit mode is definitely an option.  I've played with both.  The only problem is that the code base I'm porting was written for AIX in 32-bit mode, and when I've built things in 64-bit mode they definitely hit run-time bugs based on integer-pointer casts.  These were a pain to debug, and in 32-bit mode (even though gcc will still warn about them), the code will work.  It's a big code base, so I thought a 32-bit port was safer.  And BTW, my original post was wrong - _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code that was failing was calling fseek, not ftell.

fseek does *not* return the file position.